# Export CSV As UTF-8 Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, encoding

I have an angular app where user can export a table to CSV. Although it works fine in desktop, when trying to open it in mobile I receive the following error:
"Unable to open the document spreadsheet appears to be corrupted".
I used this site 
https://csvlint.io
to check the CSV, and received this warning:

"Context problem: Incorrect Encoding
Your CSV appears to be encoded in ASCII-8BIT. We recommend you use UTF-8."

After searching a little for solution, I found many issues about it, but my code already appear to have the solution (The BOM), so I don't know what else is missing.
This is my code ( it is a angular app)

```js
  protected exportCSV(items: any, fileName: string): void {
    const isItemsExists = Array.isArray(items) && items.length > 0;
    if (!isItemsExists) {
      this.alertService.showTranslatedMessage('dataExporterService.errors.noItemToExport', '', MessageSeverity.error);
      return;
    }

    const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value; // specify how you want to handle null values here
    const header = Object.keys(items[0]);
    const csv = items.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
    csv.unshift(header.join(','));
    const csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');
    const BOM = '\uFEFF'; // Use this and utf8 to support hebrew
    const blob = new Blob([BOM + csvArray], {
      type: 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8'
    });

    this.fileSaver.save(blob, fileName);
  }
```